# Extract rows where ID is matching but suffix is not present in another table

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where two tables (`table1` has columns `Id` and `IDSuffix` and `table2` has columns `TableID`, `TableIDSuffix` and `Name`) have matching ID, but the suffix associated with ID may or may not present in `Table2`.

How to identify those suffixes which is present in `table1`, but absent in table2?

**Table1**

| ID | IDSuffix |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 |
| 101 | 8 |
| 101 | 9 |
| 412 | 0 |
| 412 | 5 |
| 412 | 9 |
| 215 | 0 |
| 215 | 9 |
| 518 | 0 |
| 518 | 9 |

**Table2**

| TableID | TableIDSuffix | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | Tom |
| 101 | 0 | Mel |
| 101 | 9 | Tom |
| 101 | 9 | Mel |
| 412 | 0 | Gab |
| 412 | 9 | Gab |
| 215 | 0 | Kit |
| 215 | 0 | Hary |
| 215 | 9 | Hary |
| 518 | 0 | Jo |
| 518 | 9 | J0 |
| 518 | 0 | Kia |
| 518 | 9 | Kia |

Required output should be like this:

| ID | IDSuffix | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 8 | Tom |
| 101 | 8 | Mel |
| 412 | 5 | Gab |
| 215 | 9 | Kit |

I used the left join in my query like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.IDSuffix, b.TableIDSuffix, b.Name
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID = b.TableID 
                   AND a.IDSuffix = b.TableIDSuffix
GROUP BY a.ID, a.IDSuffix, b.TableIDSuffix, b.Name
```

I was expecting `b.TableIDSuffix` will be `NULL` so that I can extract those rows, but what I see for example for `ID = 101` for IDSuffix 8 there is only one NULL in `TableIDSuffix` - there should be two for both Tom and Mel as shown in the expected result table.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to run your example data through any local session in SSMS:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#table1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #table1
CREATE TABLE #table1(
    ID          INT
    ,IDSuffix   INT
)
INSERT INTO #table1 (ID,IDSuffix)
VALUES (101,0)
,(101,8)
,(101,9)
,(412,0)
,(412,5)
,(412,9)
,(215,0)
,(215,9)
,(518,0)
,(518,9)

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#table2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #table2
CREATE TABLE #table2(
    TableID         INT
    ,TableIDSuffix  INT
    ,[Name]         VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO #table2 (TableID,TableIDSuffix,[Name])
VALUES (101,0,'Tom')
,(101,0,'Mel')
,(101,9,'Tom')
,(101,9,'Mel')
,(412,0,'Gab')
,(412,9,'Gab')
,(215,0,'Kit')
,(215,0,'Hary')
,(215,9,'Hary')
,(518,0,'Jo')
,(518,9,'J0')
,(518,0,'Kia')
,(518,9,'Kia')
```

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
SELECT A.ID
    ,A.IDSuffix
    ,B.[Name]
    ,C.TableID
FROM #table1 A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            b.TableID
            ,b.[Name]
        FROM #table2 b
        ) B
        ON A.ID = B.TableID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 C
        ON A.ID = C.TableID
        AND A.IDSuffix = C.TableIDSuffix
        AND b.[Name] = C.[Name]
WHERE C.TableID IS NULL
```

In this case, your second table needed to be restructured for all existing combinations of name and ID. We can join that to T1 for all possible combinations of all 3 columns.

Then, we can filter for the mis-matches between this adjusted T1 and T2.

[image]

Then with the WHERE clause:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. But if you see ID 215  (Table1) , Hary (Table2) is on both suffixes (0 and 9) But Kit is only on 0 . So the resut set has missing record of  Kit with 9 Suffix.

Comment: Thanks alot. But if you see ID 215 (Table1) , Hary (Table2) is on both suffixes (0 and 9) But Kit is only on 0 . So the query resut has missing record of Kit with 9 Suffix.

Comment: A little harder than I thought. Adjusted the answer above!